# Show Desktop causes a taskbar item to blink/flash indefinitely

Tags: windows, windows-vista, taskbar

Sometimes when I use Windows's "Show Desktop" button (the one built into Quick Launch), one of the items on the taskbar starts blinking/flashing and won't stop until I give it focus.  This doesn't happen every time I use the button, but I'd say it happens more than half the time.  I haven't noticed a pattern for which item blinks, or when the problem occurs.

Curiously, this happens on both my home computer, which runs Vista, and my work computer, which runs XP.  Anyone have ideas on how to make it stop?  It's not a major problem by any stretch of the imagination, but it's getting kind of irritating, mostly because it gives me a nagging *"Something... Is Not Right"* feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Run TweakUI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe), "General" tab, check the box, "Prevent applications from
stealing focus", uncheck "Flash taskbar button until I click on it",
"Apply", "OK"

Comment: I thought TweakUI was only for XP; is there a Vista equivalent?

Comment: Vista Tweaker - http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html

Comment: Well, how about that?  +1/accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but I do have an alternate method of invoking that Show Desktop functionality. I long ago deleted that shortcut from the quick Launch toolbar to reclaim the real estate. To show the desktop I use Win+D, which does the exact same thing. Win+M is similar; it does Minimize All Windows. (Win+D is a toggle, Win+M is not.)

So, try either of those. Perhaps they'll alleviate your particular nag.  Which I guess is an answer of sorts.

Comment: Win+D seems to work.  However, I noticed that it doesn't maintain vertical order when it brings windows back up.  Win+M is nice -- it's the behavior I actually WANT the "Show Desktop" button to have -- but it doesn't solve this particular problem.